# is there a way to get org-mode to display dates in words?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to get org-mode to insert and display timestamp dates as words, not in export but in the org-mode buffer?

So i.e. instead of inserting a date as <2013-01-28 Mon> it would show Monday, January 28th, 2013?

I'm looking at org-time-stamp-custom-formats and format-time-string but I don't see any answers there.

Answer (score 2):

You can customise the org-mode variable `org-time-stamp-custom-formats`:

```
M-x customize-variable <RET> org-time-stamp-custom-formats <RET>
```

Then change the format from `%m/%d/%y %a` to `%A, %B %d, %Y`. To change how a timestamp is shown in a buffer, put the point over the timestamp and press `C-c C-x C-t`.

You can see the syntax for the date format by looking at the help with `C-h f org-time-stamp-custom-formats`.

Comment: The current method for Emacs 24.3.50 (9.0) syntax date format information is `C-h f format-time-string`.